# Fatal error: SourceGuardian Loader - This script is expired. Please contact the author of the script regarding this

Tags: php, apache

I protected my source code using SourceGuardian Loader 11.1 but i now recieve the error below when i run my project
    Fatal error: SourceGuardian Loader - This script is expired. Please    contact the author of the script regarding this problem. Error code [09] in C:\projects\sel16p\pages\login.php on line 2

Comment: Are we supposed to know what is in **login.php on line 2**  without seeing it?

Comment: The line 2 on that login.php is encoded. using SourceGuardian. The encoded script is working on a different computer.

Comment: _The line 2 on that login.php is encoded..._ Hmm.. so good luck finding your answer then

Comment: So, i fail to understand why that happens because i installed apache and php manually yet the same script is running well on XAMPP win32-5.6.15-2-VC11

Comment: Its an issue with source guardian sir

Answer (score 1):

I've never used SourceGuardian but it seems that you will have to lock your original script with a new date because it has expired. If you don't have it, you will have to contact the author.

from: [user's manual](https://sourceguardian.com/demofiles/files/SourceGuardian%20for%20Linux%20User%20Manual.pdf)

```
|       Err        |  Code   |   Default message           |
+------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
| License expired  |   09    |   This script has expired...|
```

> ## Locking options
>
> ```
> --expire [dd/mm/yyyy]
> ```
>
> This option lets you set an expiration date for the script. The script will not run on and after the specified
>   date and display the following error message: "This script has expired".